# Application running within a docker container is not accessible?

Tags: docker

I have create a docker image with all the setup to run my Django application .
Step 1:

```
docker images 
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sidhartha03/django   latest              c4ba9ec8e613        About an hour ago   704 MB
```

Step 2:

```
docker run -i -t c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash
```

Step 3:

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/# cd /home
```

Step 4:Activate the virtual env

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/home# source my_env/bin/activate
```

Step 5:

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/home# cd my_project_directory
```

Step 6:Gunicorn bind coomand to deploy the Django application

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/home/my_project_directory# gunicorn OPC.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --daemon
```

Step 7:Restart Nginx

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/home/my_project_directory# sudo service nginx restart
```

Step 8:check wheather the application is running or not

```
root@257f4e73ffa0:/home/my_project_directory# netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22/python
```

---> But the application is not accessible 127.0.0.1:8000
getting the following in browser
This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the container port where you run your gunicorn to the host. To do this, use the following command.

`docker run -i -t -p 8000:8000 c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash`

Comment: Do you have an nginx server listen on your port 8000 on the host network? That error doesn't make sense since in your container only gunicorn is running.

Comment: Its working fine but when I am exiting the docker terminal the application is getting stopped .How to put it in background ?

Comment: Add the option -d (detached mode) to your `docker run`. 

 `docker run -i -t -d -p 8000:8000 c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash`

Comment: But the running the container in detached mode does not run the application with it .After "docker run. docker run -i -t -d -p 8000:8000 c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash"  this command to access the container "docker attach container_id(c4ba9ec8e613)" I am using .Then I am able to run the application .

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I haven't used the Dockerfile .I am manually doing the setup with in the Docker container .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142569/discussion-between-sidhartha-and-jose-antonio-lopez).